# how to find value inside pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, find

I have a pandas column :'function' ,of jobs functions:
IT,HR etc..
but I have them in few variations for each function.
('IT application','IT,Digital,Digital' etc..)
I wanted to change all values that contains IT -> IT for example.

I tried:

```
df['function'].str.contains('IT')
df['function'].isin(['IT'])
```

which gives only partial results.

I wanted something like:
'IT' in df.loc[:,'function']

but a solution that would work for all the column and not for 1 index at a time.
if there is a solution that doesn't need a loop that would be great.

Comment: Do you mean you have a column called function with rows containing STRING values such as 'HR', 'IT' etc? Secondly are you saying that you currently have the Value 'IT-' but you want to replace this with 'IT'?

Comment: the answer to the first question is yes, 'function' is just a column name. and i want to replace all things that contains 'IT' but contains mor chars like 'IT,Digital,Digital' to 'IT'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

df['function'] = df.function.str.replace(r'(^.*IT.*$)', 'IT')

Comment: tnx, but it didnt work..:/